# Reducing this Haskell function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I want to double every second element of a list. Here is the code-

```
doubleSec n [] = []
doubleSec n (x:xs)
    | n==1 = x*2 : doubleSec 0 xs
    | otherwise = x : doubleSec 1 xs 

doubleSecond xs =
    doubleSec 0 xs
```

How can I compact this logic in a single function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
doubleSecond xs = map (\(x,i) -> if odd i then x*2 else x) (zip xs [0..])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can match a pattern on the list like this

```
doubleSec :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleSec [] = []
doubleSec [x] = [x]
doubleSec (x : y : xs) = x : 2* y : doubleSec xs
```

letting you do specific things to the second element

Answer (score 2):

This method will preserve the O(n) running time:

```
doubleSecond xs =
  [ if isOddStep then 2 * x else x | 
    (isOddStep, x) <- zip (cycle [False, True]) xs ]
```

---

An more succinct version by @DavidFletcher:

```
doubleSecond = zipWith ($) (cycle [id, (2*)])
```

or:

```
doubleSecond = zipWith id (cycle [id, (2*)])
```

as suggested by @Carl.

Comment: If you're going to use cycle, then `zipWith ($) (cycle [id, (2*)])`

Comment: @DavidFletcher If you're going to golf that, `zipWith id` is slightly shorter (and easier to type) than `zipWith ($)`